# Language of an interpreter

Tags: java, interpreters

I am trying to make my own programming language by making an interpreter for it in Java, but lately people have been telling me that an interpreter needs to be in the same language as the one it is interpreting. Is this true? Then what am I building?

Comment: related: [Why are self-hosting compilers considered a rite of passage for new languages?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/263651/31260)

Comment: The link is talking specifically about compilers while I've asked specifically about interpreters, I don't think it is a duplicate. If it is so, then why is it okay to have python interpreters to be in other languages?

Comment: “people have been telling me that an interpreter needs to be in the same language as the one it is interpreting” – that's total bullshit. Very few interpreters are [“metacircular”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-circular_evaluator) or “self-hosted”. The OpenJDK HotSpot Java bytecode interpreter is written in C++. The Perl and CPython interpreters are written in C. Note also that compilers and interpreters are closely related (it is not always possible to make a clear distinction). For example, a non-self-hosted interpreter may be used during bootstrapping of a self-hosted compiler.

Comment: Aah that clears things up alot, I was feeling down that all I was doing was in vain xD

Comment: Interpreter vs. compiler is not a quality of a language, per se, but rather of an implementation of the language.  One language can have both compiled and interpreted implementations.  Ultimately, you'll need at least one compiler (or assembler) of some language in your stack -- unless you want to toggle machine code directly into the front panel ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it isn't true.

To use the same language, you would also need to have a compiler for that language, so that you could compile the interpreter to machine code.

If all you have is an interpreter, then you would just end up with interpreters all the way down.  To run the interpreter, you would need an interpreter.  To run that second interpreter, you would need a third one, and so on.

Comment: So is any language which is only interpreted a language at all? Also, if I'm using Java as the language for the interpreter, then is my language running on a VM or getting directly interpreted into an output?

Comment: @bhalec If you can write meaningful programs in it, then it's a language.  How that language gets run doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @bhalec If your interpreter is in Java, then it's compilcated.  The interpreter itself gets compiled into Java byte code.  The byte code is either compiled or interpreted by the JVM - the JVM decides that for itself at run time.  Your language then runs on the interpreter, inside the JVM.  That's why simplistic statements about what is a language are meaningless.

Comment: @bhalec compilers and interpreters are *software*. The main difference is when they run in relation to the user program. A compiler is run once, ahead of time. An interpreter is running alongside the program it interprets. A *language* exists independently of any software *implementations* (compilers or interpreters). E.g. Java is *defined* by a bunch of *English text*, published by Oracle.

Comment: @bhalec A programming language is a formal system for describing algorithms. Interpretation or compilation are details of an implementation of a programming language. You could write an interpreter for C or a machine-code compiler for Javascript. The existence of either wouldn't change anything about these languages.

Comment: @Philipp: "You could write an interpreter for C or a machine-code compiler for Javascript." – Actually, there *are* interpreters for C, and *every single widely-used* implementation of JavaScript uses a machine-code compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The Factor programming language started as a Java interpreter, as have many others.  For encouragement and enlightenment, I suggest studying or at least looking at, the following books: [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193435659X), [Seven More Languages in Seven Weeks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1941222153), and [Masterminds of Programming: Conversations with the Creators of Major Programming Languages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596515170).  I'm constantly researching languages, and trying to learn about them, and what I've listed are some of my favorite books on the subject, but by no means the only ones of course.

Also, I'm currently writing a Forth-like concatenative interpreter in C#.  That's one of the easiest interpreters to make, because it's strictly space-delimited, strictly left-to-right, postfix, and homoiconic, like LISP, so any macros or metaprogramming is the same shape as the language itself, not an additional language bolted-on like the preprocessor macros of C and C++.  (Not that I'm against them, but it **is** a whole new langauge to learn on top of the main language, instead of like Lisp, where the macros are written **in** the language itself, and have the full power thereof.)

Finally, this book, [Let over Lambda](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435712757), is a mind-blower that covers the power of Lisp macros.  I found most of it online on [Doug's web site](https://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/toc).  There's a chapter, "Lisp Moving Forth Moving Lisp", which I still haven't read that has really piqued my interest.

Keep writing your interpreter in Java.  Don't let the stinkers hold you down!

Also, if you look in the "Seven More Languages" book in the Factor language chapter, at the interview with Slava Pestov, the inventor of Factor, which at first was written in Java, he describes how he ultimately transitioned his language to being separate from Java.  He used an image model for compiled code, and gave his language the ability to write out the image.  Then he created a virtual machine, and REPL interpreter in the C language, and finally gave his new C kernel the ability to load an image, wrote out the image from Java, read the image into his C-kernel version, and presto, eureka, he suddenly had a new language no longer dependent on JAVA.  Not that you have to go that way.  But it was way interesting.  Keep going!

Answer (score 0):

You want a language that’s good for writing interpreters. You might want to write a COBOL interpreter. Never in a million years would you write one in COBOL.

So this statement is utter nonsense. Go ahead and write your interpreter in Java.